# React on long tap in the Preferences?

Tags: android, preferences

I am creating a Custom Preference. Is there any way to react not just on click, but on long tap/click as well? So, if user clicks on the preference, then one event happens (dialog to choose the value opens), if long tap - another.

Comment: Please see the answer in the link, [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912388/how-to-add-a-long-click-listener-to-a-preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a LongClickListener on a preference itself but you can add it to the backing ListView of the PreferenceActivity and get the same behavior. See this [tutorial](http://kmansoft.com/2011/08/29/implementing-long-clickable-preferences/).

Comment: Emphasis on "a preference itself"... not the whole thing sadly. I had to do this:   findPreference("pref_key").setOnPreferenceClickListener(clickListener);