# Is it possible to add long press listener to CheckBoxPreference?

Tags: android, listener, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference

The answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912388/how-to-add-a-long-click-listener-to-a-preference) are not helping in any way.
I have one requirement where `I want to do something when user long presses on CheckBoxPreference`. I am dynamically creating the CheckBoxPreference inside activity. I am using below piece of code to populate the view:

```
m_PreferenceScreen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);    
m_PreferenceCategory = new PreferenceCategory(this);    
m_CheckBoxPreference = new CheckBoxPreference[m_Cursor.getCount()];
int i = 0;    
while (m_Cursor.moveToNext()) {    
    //Create checkbox instances here    
    m_CheckBoxPreference[i].setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);     
    m_PreferenceCategory.addPreference(m_CheckBoxPreference[i++]);    
}    
setPreferenceScreen(m_PreferenceScreen);
```

**On what I am trying to achieve?**
I have few entries in database. I want to populate a list of checkboxes corresponding to each entry in database(I am able to do it with above code). Now my requirement is, when user long presses on any checkbox, it should do something(Say, open a dialog box).

Is this thing doable with above piece of code?
I will also appreciate any alternate solution.   However, I would prefer going with the first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this. The below trick works for me.

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    Object obj = listAdapter.getItem(position);
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof View.OnLongClickListener) {
        View.OnLongClickListener longListener = (View.OnLongClickListener) obj;
        return longListener.onLongClick(view);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if CheckBoxPreference has a long press component or not.  You might want to evaluate your UX to see if you can replace the action with a different UI component.  Perhaps it is a regular preference that when click opens your details as well as a checkbox that can be checked.

If this doesn't suit your needs you can manually create checkbox views that can automatically load/update the shared preference object.  I believe the standard view checkbox has the ability to be long pressed.  It might be something to sample out since I've never directly tried long pressing a checkbox.  If you cannot you might need to create a checkbox and a separate component that contains the text to be long pressed.